# what is domain location of weblogic application server?

Tags: weblogic-10.x

I am new to weblogic.I am trying to configure liferay with weblogic.
I want to put liferay dependency jar files inside lib folder of domain.

Now i am confused because in Oracle>Middleware>user_projects>domains there are two folders that contains lib folder.

1)base_domain
2)my_domain.

Can someone let me know where should i put all dependency jar files?

Comment: The right answer would be: "on the domain where your managed server belongs to". But since they are only two, why not trying each one and see which of them works?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, make sure which domain you are using. base_domain and my_domain are not the ones shipped with weblogic. They are the ones created for app deployment.

Please check where your application is deployed and then place your jar in that domain.